# Comparing Class objects

Tags: java

I have to compare a `Class` object against a list of pre-defined classes.

Is it safe to use `==` or should I use `equals`?

```
if        (klass == KlassA.class) {
} else if (klass == KlassB.class) {
} else if (klass == KlassC.class) {
} else {
}
```

**Note:** I cannot use `instanceof`, I don't have an object, I just have the `Class` object. I (mis)use it like an enum in this situation!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`java.lang.Class` [does not](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) override the `equals` method from `java.lang.Object`, which is implemented like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

So `a == b` is the same as `a.equals(b)` (except if `a` is null).

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this will work for your specific situation, but you could try [Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)).

```
KlassA.class.isAssignableFrom(klass)
```

Comment: Or because types are reflexive you could also use klassA.isAssignableFrom(klasB) && klassB.isAssignableFrom(klasA) for equality

Comment: @Steiny, that sounds like an overkill, for equality we can just compare class references.

Answer (score 3):

For the most of the Java applications this is correct. However, comparing Java classes using the operator == is safe just if both the classes are loaded by the same classloader.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Two classes with the same name but loaded by different class loaders will not have the same address nor will they be the same class. So `==` would be false and that would be correct. If the OP wanted to compare class names that would be different (and then use `klass.getName().equals(xxxx.class.getName())`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in previous answers, to compare objects of Class type (or java.lang.Class objects) we should use == operator. However, It may be a bit confusing because always the result of comparison between objects through == operator can not cause right results (we usually use equal() method). For example, the result of this expression is false:

```
new String("book") == new String("book")//false
```

The reason is that,

> The virtual machine manages **a unique Class object for each type**.
>   Therefore, you can use the == operator to compare java.lang.Class
>   **objects**. From [Core Java for the Impatient - Page 153](https://books.google.com/books?id=cfJzBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=The%20virtual%20machine%20manages%20a%20unique%20Class%20object%20for%20each%20type.%20Therefore&source=bl&ots=qePrLJZJQY&sig=IE9grdGSGkvhIagZcS3e72-mq3o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlkfGFr6_XAhVpLsAKHblHDlMQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=The%20virtual%20machine%20manages%20a%20unique%20Class%20object%20for%20each%20type.%20Therefore&f=false)

Therefore:

```
new String("book").getClass() == new String("book").getClass()//true
```

or

```
Class.forName("java.lang.String") == Class.forName("java.lang.String")//true
```

result in true.

Comment: It's not strictly true that only one class will exist with a given name per virtual machine. Since ClassLoader is a part of Class object identity, several loaders which have concurrently loaded class with the same name will produce two classes that aren't equal.

Comment: First, thanks  for your comment. Your point is correct, according oracle doc: "A class is determined by its full name and the class loader". As I am sure you know, Class.forName(...) returns a Class object corresponding to a class package and name, which is located in caller or current class loader. As, classLoader.loadClass(className) is used for getting Class object to a special class loader. So, in current class loader we can use Class.forName(...) to comparison.

Comment: what I'm saying is - you indeed can compare result of several `Class.forName` calls in single expression, but if you save the `Class` object in a field somewhere and stored it, then it won't necessarily be always equal to results of later calls to `Class.forName` from different classloading contexts. This was a problem for several pretty big libraries in the past, which is why I felt like it should be mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably safe.

If the object doesn't override the `Equals` method it will make a comparison between the references. And if two variables point to the same object, their references match.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use == for comparison between class objects and enum constants because it results in compilation time errors in case of incompatible types.

For example:

```
Class<?> cls1 = Void.class;
String cls2 = "java.lang.String";

if (cls1 == cls2) doSomething();        // Won't compile

if (cls1.equals(cls2)) doSomething();   // Will compile
```