# How to compare two classes

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm trying to create a factory, here's the code:

```
public class MyFactory {
    public static <T> MyBase create(Class<T> _c) {
        if (_c.getClass().equals(Derived1.class)) // (1)
            return createNewDerived1();

        return null;
    }
}

// caller
MyFactory.create(Derived1.class);
```

It compiles with warning at line `(1)`:

### Error

```
'equals()' between objects of inconvertible types 'Class<Derived1>'
 and 'Class<capture of ? extends Class>' Reports calls to .equals()
 where the target and argument are of incompatible types. While such a
 call might theoretically be useful, most likely it represents a bug.
```

And in runtime my `if` statement fails for some reason.
How can I get the intended behaviour?

Comment: Read about `instance of`

Comment: you can check if current object is `instanceof` your desired class or not..

Comment: I don't manipulate objects AFAIK

Comment: Arey you trying to see if the input is of class `Derived1`?

Comment: @SlashG I'm trying to pass type  `Derived1` to my `create` function and get object of that type in return

Comment: As @Enzokie and @Mohit suggested, you should read about `instanceof`. Your check can be shrunken to `if(_c instanceof Derived1)`

Comment: I am not so sure about instanceof. The point is: he is passing some **class** object. Classes are never instances of Derived.class; only instantiated objects are.

Comment: Hint: maybe isAssignableFrom () can help ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496928/what-is-the-difference-between-instanceof-and-class-isassignablefrom )

Comment: @SlashG I'm from c++ background and I thought call `create(Derived1.class)` passes type, not an object. And if so then `instanceof`of no use here?

Comment: `_c.equals(Derived1.class)` should do the job

Comment: why use `equals` at all? either use `==` for classes, or `isAssignableFrom` - depending on exact use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare class objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647257/compare-class-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class MyFactory {
    public static <T> MyBase create(Class<T> _c) {
        return ( _c == Derived1.class ) ? createNewDerived1() : null;
    }
}

// caller
MyFactory.create(Derived1.class);
```

See [Compare class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647257/compare-class-objects) for further info.

<sub>FIY, "real" class object references have `Class<MyClass>` type signatures (before erasure), while the `Class` returned by `.class` class is, AFAIR, just rawtype `Class` on some environments and `Class<capture of ?>`-ish on others.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The problem of your code

```
public static <T> MyBase create(Class<T> _c) {
    if (_c.getClass().equals(Derived1.class)) // (1)
        return createNewDerived1();

    return null;
}
```

is that you want to compare the class represented by `_c` with the literal `Derived1.class`, but you have an unnecessary `getClass()` invocation on the `Class` object. Invoking `getClass` on a `Class` object will return the object representing the class `java.lang.Class`, which you surely don’t want to compare with `Derived1`, so the warning is a good thing.

The solution is to remove the `getClass()` invocation. If you replace `equals` with an identity comparison, `==`, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38222823/2711488), it doesn’t hurt. Classes are always represented by a single canonical `Class` instance, so the semantic of `equals` and `==` is the same for `Class` instances.

But note that your generic signature is questionable.

If the provided `Class` object is intended to specify the type of the created instance, but the return type is always `MyBase`, you surely want to restrict the parameter to be assignable to `MyBase`, e.g.

```
public static <T extends MyBase> MyBase create(Class<T> _c) {
    if(c.equals(Derived1.class))
        return createNewDerived1();

    return null;
}
```

but you don’t need a type parameter here; changing the signature to

```
public static MyBase create(Class<? extends MyBase> _c)
```

bears the same semantic.

Or you decide to specify that the returned type is guaranteed to be of the type specified by the parameter (if that’s the intention). Then, you should change the method to

```
public static <T extends MyBase> T create(Class<T> _c) {
    return c==Derived1.class? _c.cast(createNewDerived1()): null;
}
```

or

```
public static <T extends MyBase> T create(Class<T> _c) {
    return c==Derived1.class? _c.cast(createNewDerived1()): _c.newInstance();
}
```

etc.

which you can use like

```
Derived1 obj = MyFactory.create(Derived1.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but `MyBase` isn't related to `T` in a ways you mentioned :)